# UnknownHostException: eu-automl.googleapis.com when call to automl API from java application

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-automl

i tried to call to the API 
@ POST eu-automl.googleapis.com:443/v1beta1/projects/{project_id}/locations/eu/models/{model_id}:predict
via java application and getting error below -

```
**Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: eu-automl.googleapis.com
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
    at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$JdkAddressResolver.resolveAddress(DnsNameResolver.java:646)
    at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver.resolveAll(DnsNameResolver.java:404)**
```

When i run this api via postman then it's pass without error.
The code which call to this API:

```
        **CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider =
                   FixedCredentialsProvider.create(
                     ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(
                             new FileInputStream(key)));
        PredictionServiceSettings settings =
                   PredictionServiceSettings.newBuilder()
                  .setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
                  .setEndpoint("eu-automl.googleapis.com:443")
                  .build();
        try (PredictionServiceClient client = PredictionServiceClient.create(settings)) {
            // Get the full path of the model.
            ModelName name = ModelName.of(projectId, "eu", modelId);
            URL url = TablesPredict.class.getResource("predict.json");
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(url.getPath()), "ASCII");
            ExamplePayload.Builder builder = ExamplePayload.newBuilder();
            JsonFormat.parser().merge(reader, builder);
            ExamplePayload payload = builder.build();
            PredictRequest request =
                    PredictRequest.newBuilder()
                    .setName(name.toString())
                    .setPayload(payload)                    
                    .putParams("feature_importance", "true")
                    .build();
            PredictResponse response = client. predict(request);
}**
```

Any idea what am i missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I do not see anything strange in the java code you shared since you are specifying correctly the EU endpoint as described [in the GCP](https://cloud.google.com/automl-tables/docs/locations#automl_set_endpoint-java) and [in the java](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-automl/1.1.1/com/google/cloud/automl/v1/PredictionServiceClient.html) documentation.

Can you check if there is a problem with the firewall configuration on your side? You can do this by simply pinging the endpoint `eu-automl.googleapis.com`